# How is this conversation possible?

Tags: inequality, fractions

I recently came upon an inequality, where the writer did something like this :-

$$\frac{-1}{2}<2^{-x}<4$$
$$\Rightarrow0<2^{-x}<2^2$$

He turned $\frac{-1}{2}$ to $0$. How is this possible? Please explain

Here is the link . If you want to see the complete question:-

[Link of question](https://byjus.com/question-answer/if-x-epsilon-r-the-solution-set-of-the-equation-4-x-0-5-7-11/)

Comment: Because $2$ in any power will be positive. It's never even zero. This does not mean that $-\frac{1}{2}=0$

Comment: Your link gives (in Europe) "Service Unavailable in EU region
217.149.169.89
7b44184aa926c265
AT
Access denied". So better not to use such links.

Answer (score 2):

$2^{-x}>0$ regardless of the value of $x$. The writer just ignored the lower bound $-\frac12$ because it brings no information at all, and replaced it with the sharper bound 0.