# How is this change possible?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, exponentiation, fractions, infinity

I came upon an inequality :-

$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^∞<\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x<\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-2}$

Then the writer wrote:-

Since , $\frac{1}{2}<1$ ,$$-2<x<∞$$

Please explain me clearly how he did this ?

Comment: $(1/2)^\infty$ is meaningless.

Comment: The other inequality can be written as $2^{-x}<2^2$ for $-x<2,$ which is just a result of the fact that $f(y)=2^y$ is an increasing function.

Comment: If $0 < a < b$, which is larger, $\frac{1}{a}$ or $\frac{1}{b}$?  If $m < n$, which is larger, $2^m$ or $2^n$?

Comment: Maybe related to the [question earlier about $\left(\frac12\right)^\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4674611/89922).

Comment: Maybe related to the [question earlier about inequality $0 < 2^{-x} < 2^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4674674/89922).

Comment: Where did you "come upon" this inequality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the logarithm of all terms. We can do this since log is a monotonic increasing function. Since $\frac{1}{2}<1$, its logarithm is negative, which causes the direction of the inequalities to flip.